# is there a way to double words in string containing specific character in ABAP, SAP?

Tags: string, character, abap, statements

One string is given. Please double every word in string, which starts with symbol “a”. Words separated by space symbol. For example:

- Input: I have an apple in my apartment
- Output: I have an an apple apple in my apartment apartment

Answer (score 5):

There are multiple ways to do that.

You could use `SPLIT string AT space INTO TABLE DATA(tokens)` to tokenize the string into its words, then `LOOP AT tokens` to reassemble the words into a new string, doubling the token if `to_lower( token(1) ) = 'a'`.

Alternatively, you could use regular expressions to match all words that start with `a` or `A`, then use the matching positions to repeat the matched words. You'd have to work out the reg ex on your own, though.

You could also build an automaton that looks at one character after another, reaching a specific state if it encounters a word that starts in "a", and then cloning the matched word. This sounds a little over the top, though, and would better fit more complex cases like building a parser.

> Your question sounds meaningless from a business perspective, so I assume it's a question in homework. Instead of providing a fully fledged, working answer, I therefore only outline possible ways to approach the problem.
>
> According to [*How Do I Ask and Answer Homework Questions?*](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/334822/how-do-i-ask-and-answer-homework-questions), you shouldn't simply forward these questions but rather provide what you already tried and in what specific place you have troubles. Otherwise people will vote to close your question, and they have indeed already begun to do that.